# Can Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage be FIPS 140-2 compliant

Tags: c#, encryption, azure-blob-storage, fips

Our current code is using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.3.2. I have started testing out running our web app on a Windows laptop with FIPS compliance enforced. The app throws a FIPS compliance error every time it attempts to upload or download a blob from Azure, saying the encryption method is not allowed. One chunk of code that throws errors looks like this:

```
var cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(<auth callback object>);
var encryptionThingy = await cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(<Key Vault URL> + "/keys/" + <key name>, CancellationToken.None);
var policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, cloudResolver);
var options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
await <ICloudBlob Instance>.DownloadToStreamAsync(<stream>, null, options, null);
```

I went up into the Azure KeyVault and checked the key being used, it is 2048 bit RSA (which should be allowed). Is that enough for FIPS compliance, or would I also have to turn on an expiration/rollover date? Currently the key does not expire and all operations are permitted on it.

Comment: Did you try googling. The second link i found (this was the first) was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption, which says "Data in Azure Storage is encrypted and decrypted transparently using 256-bit AES encryption, one of the strongest block ciphers available, and is FIPS 140-2 compliant." So the answer to your question is _Yes_. The obvious follow on is _How to get it working?_ That, I don't know

Comment: Yes, I know that's what the MS docs say. But in my experience MS documentation is sometimes little better than marketing material. Perhaps this title needs to be changed.

Comment: My experience is different. I worked in their support organization for a dozen years, doing high end developer support; I relied on their public documentation. You probably need to ask a separate question about how to get this to work together. IIRC, getting FIPS encryption working requires getting everything lined up on both ends. Example: (again from memory) it was impossible to have a combine Windows XP & Vista FIPS compatible configuration; there was no overlap between the algorithms certified for each OS

Comment: Well, if we were gonna argue about that we'd have to go to FB or Reddit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is no. I've tested rewriting the Blob access with v12 of Azure.Storage.Blobs ([How do you decrypt blobs with Azure KeyVault keys in Azure.Storage v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239116/how-do-you-decrypt-blobs-with-azure-keyvault-keys-in-azure-storage-v12)) and it works fine while using the older libraries throws the error.